# Legacy Audio Shortcode

Tags: shortcode, audio

I have recently redone a site that was originally created in 2011. Of course there were a few big development issues and one of them is the usage of an old audio shortcode:

[audio:http://localhost:8888/lusa/audio/1310seg02.mp3]

I have not seen any documentation of the native Wordpress audio shortcode ever using a colon. I have also not been able to find a plugin that uses it in this way.

Does anyone know how I can get this shortcode functioning? I believe my options are.

1. Create a script that turns this audio shortcode into the newer format [audio src="http://localhost:8888/lusa/audio/1310seg02.mp3] https://codex.wordpress.org/Audio_Shortcode.
2. Find the plugin that originally made the shortcode this way.
3. ?

/*======== Progress ========*/

@gmazzap got me on the right track! The issue is that with the shortcode_atts_audio hook the $atts variable doesn't output strings outside of the predefined attributes (src, loop, autoplay, preload.) After some digging I found that I can use the wp_audio_shortcode_override to access my url. That is what I'm doing in the code below. But now I'm having trouble passing that attribute back into the shortcode and outputting it.

```
function legacy_audio_shortcode_converter( $html, $attr ) {

        $colon_src = $attr[0]; //get the url string with the colon included.
        $attr['src'] = substr($colon_src, 1); //filter out the colon
        $new_audio_src = $attr['src']; //save the url as the official audio src
        var_dump($new_audio_src); //this is currently outputing the exact url I need but not sure how to make sure the player shows up with this new src.
}

add_filter( 'wp_audio_shortcode_override', 'legacy_audio_shortcode_converter', 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your only issue is that the format is incorrect then switch it in [`the_content`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content) hook with the correct version.

---

Non-local content:

```
[audio:http://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-7.mp3]
```

Place in a plugin or functions.php

```
// hook earlier than 10

add_filter('the_content', 'wpse_20160110_the_content_fix_audio', 0);

function wpse_20160110_the_content_fix_audio($content){
    return str_replace ( '[audio:', '[audio src=', $content );
}
```

Comment: awesome. that worked great. Simple.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use `'shortcode_atts_audio'` filter hook to convert the arguments in the proper form, and let the default audio shortcode handler render it.

In fact, with a shortcode like `[audio:http://localhost:8888/lusa/audio/1310seg02.mp3]` the shortcode handler will be called with an argument array that is

```
array(0 => ':http://localhost:8888/lusa/audio/1310seg02.mp3');
```

Where the proper formatted argument array should be

```
array('src' => 'http://localhost:8888/lusa/audio/1310seg02.mp3');
```

So you can do:

```
add_filter( 'shortcode_atts_audio', function(array $atts) {
  if (
    empty($atts['src'])
    && ! empty($atts[0])
    && filter_var(ltrim($atts[0], ':'), FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)
  ) {
      $atts['src'] = ltrim($atts[0], ':');
  }

  return $atts;
} );
```

In this way the default audio shortcode handler should be able to render the shortcode.

**Untested**.

Comment: Thanks @gmazzap! I didn't even consider filters. There were a few issues with the code. One being that "if (empty($atts['src']))" worked and "if (isset($atts['src']))" did not. I also found it much easier to grab my url with the colon using the wp_audio_shortcode_override hook. Unfortunately having a bit of trouble still. Can you take a look at my edited answer/code and let me know if you have any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: @Celso I fixed the code using `empty` instead of `isset` and simplified it. Now should work and be easy to understand... Why do you think that to use `wp_audio_shortcode_override` is easier? I think it is not, in fact you have problem using it ;) Reason is that  from `wp_audio_shortcode_override` you can't just change arguments, but you need to _render_ the shortcode. Moreover, my code works for **both** your legacy shortcode and for proper formatted shortcodes, this gives you chance to use the proper formatted shortcode from now.

Comment: thanks for simplifying it. The issue is that $atts variable doesn't output the string I need. It only outputs the default attributes (src, loop, autoplay, preload.) I tested just doing a var_dump($atts) and var_dump($atts[0]) using your code and could not see the string I needed. If I could get that string then this would work but unfortunately I can't.